# Read file in Shared Library Xamarin c#

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have saved some .json files in the shared library.

I have managed to read just fine in iOS by the code

```
string fileName = $"Files/file_name.json";

var path = Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, fileName);
using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (var streaReader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    return streaReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

However, I have been struggling to do the same for Android.
I can't read from assets since it is in the Shared Library.

```
using (var stream = Application.Context.Assets.Open("Files/file_name.json))
```

Using this live above does work if I had the file in the Android project under the assets folder.

I want to keep one copy of the file used for both platforms.

Answer (score 5):

1. Add your "shared" file to your solution (in a folder within your PCL/NetStd/Shared project is fine, just set the build type to `None`).
2. In your Android project, create a **link** to the file in the `Assets` with a build type of `AndroidAsset`.
3. In your iOS project, create a **link** to the file with a build type of `BundleResource`.

#### Android Example:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidAsset Include="..\Forms_30\her.png">
      <Link>Assets\her.png</Link>
    </AndroidAsset>
  </ItemGroup>
```

#### iOS Example:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <BundleResource Include="..\Forms_30\her.png">
      <Link>her.png</Link>
    </BundleResource>
 </ItemGroup>
```

Note: You can manually edit the `.csproj` or perform a drop/drop from Finder/Explorer using the starting location of the file in your PCL/NetStd library but make you select **create a link** when you drop the file.

Now you can either use your own platform-dependent code via DI or use `Xamarin.Essentials` to access these read-only app bundled files from your PCL/NetStd library.

#### Xamarin.Essentials

```
using (var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("her.png"))
{
     ~~~
}
```

Comment: Guess the only way is to manually alter the project files. I was hoping for a more native approach. But I guess your solution is the closest to the answer!

Comment: @GustavoBaiocchiCosta `...hoping for a more native approach...` Not sure what you mean by that, native to what? Also you do not have to manually alter the .csproj, you can do this via drag/drop

Comment: I will give that another try tomorrow @SushiHangover.

Comment: I tried your method again today. There is not option to create link when I drop the file in the PCL project. Xamarin.Essentials is xamarin.forms which we are not using. I am still trying to get the stream by the android way. However, I get Jave.IO.FileNotFoundException

Comment: @GustavoBaiocchiCosta You add the file to the NetStd/PCL project first, then you open FileExplorer/Finder and drag/drop that file into Android/iOS projects, you then have an option to copy, move or link... choose link, the result is the .csproj additions as shown in my answer.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this. I added the file test.json to the PCL project. Then I dropped the file into the android project and I have no option to copy, move or link. If I move over to pcl it asks if I want to replace the file.

Answer (score 1):

Are these files static (as in, they are part of the installation package), or are they saved by the application at runtime?

If they are static, you need to put them in different places depending on the platform.

For iOS you put the files in `Resources`, with a build type of `BundleResource` and access them with `NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource`.

For Android, the files go in Assets, with a build type of `AndroidAsset`, and access them with `Assets.Open`.

[This page](https://robgibbens.com/deploying-a-database-file-with-a-xamarin-forms-app/) gives you more details.

Comment: Yes, they are static. Maybe there is a way to store them in the Shared Library. It works for iOS but not for android

Answer (score 0):

AndroidAssets, Content and other command tags in a VS project file are able to use wildcards and can be used dynamically.

The command below works in a xamarin android project in VS 2019 and will add to your project all directories and files inside the given base path. Files will be  dynamically included to the /Assets when the projects is loaded and VS will show then normal included as assets. A deploy adds them in the right way as assets to your apk.

In the same way you can include them as resources using the AndroidResource tag and so on.

Please note that for CORE, older .NET variants or shared libs the format and/or names of the attributes of "include", "copyto" and  "link" are different. You have to check that carefully.

For some CORE versions it is "LinkBase=..." instead of "Link=" and so on. You better carefully check that and get the right format from the microsoft docs.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidAsset Include="PATH_TO_THE_SHARED_LIB\FOLDER_TO_INCLUDE\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" Link="Assets\%(RecursiveDir)\%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
 </ItemGroup>
```