# Xamarin Resource File Equivalent

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, resources

I'm experienced in Android development and recently starting learning Xamarin. As I build my first project, I was wondering if there's any equivalent to Android's Resource folder - specifically styles.xml, string.xml, dimen.xml, etc.

I know these exist in the Android project folder but I'm referring specifically to the Shared project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Shared project`? Are you actually taking about a Shared Code Project or a .NetStd/PCL Library Project

Comment: .Net/PCL version

Comment: `.Net/PCL version` The short answer is no, you "can" use assembly embedding of a media/resource file and then use standard .Net features to extract that embedded file from the assembly at runtime, but personally avoid doing that for almost all file types as all you are doing is inflating the size of the assembly and thus now have all those blobs in ram when the assembly is loaded. Now if you wish to consolidate the files into one project and then link them to the application projects (which I do), review this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51446357/4984832

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a `Xamarin.Android` application is first created, default resources are setup by the `Xamarin.Android` project template. Check the following url.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-resource-basics?tabs=vswin

Comment: I understand that much but I mean something that would apply to that and the iOS project. Do I just have to create a resource in both projects with the same name each time I want to add a string or drawable or whatever or is there a better way?