# Accessing asset files in .NET Standard library for WinForms, Xamarin.Forms etc

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a .NET Standard 2.0 library that's written in C#, developed with VS2019. It contains a growing number of asset files in a subdirectory that contain additional information for something the user might do. The files are marked as Content and are copied if newer. If the OS permits, the user should be able to edit these files with a 3rd party application and add new files.

In the static constructor of this library, I open the directory and parse all files:

```
public class xyz
{
  static xyz()
  {
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("./Library", "*.xml");
    foreach (string xmlFile in files)
    {
      // Open file
      XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
      xml.Load(xmlFile);
      // Do something with these files...
    }
  }

  // More stuff (it's not a static class)
}
```

If I include this library in a WinForms application, it works perfectly. Files are copied to the appropriate subdirectory of the app as expected and can be parsed.

However, when I include it in a Xamarain.Forms application, on Android I get an exception: System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'xyz' threw an exception.'

No more debugging info isn't available and I therefore cannot determine the exact point where the exception is thrown. However, console contains the following output:

> 03-18 15:02:42.118 D/Mono    (26603): DllImport searching in:
>   'libmono-native.so' ('./libmono-native.so'). 03-18 15:02:42.118 D/Mono
>   (26603): Searching for 'SystemNative_GetReadDirRBufferSize'. 03-18
>   15:02:42.118 D/Mono    (26603): Probing
>   'SystemNative_GetReadDirRBufferSize'. 03-18 15:02:42.118 D/Mono
>   (26603): Found as 'SystemNative_GetReadDirRBufferSize'. 03-18
>   15:02:42.122 D/Mono    (26603): DllImport searching in:
>   'libmono-native.so' ('./libmono-native.so'). 03-18 15:02:42.122 D/Mono
>   (26603): Searching for 'SystemNative_OpenDir'. 03-18 15:02:42.122
>   D/Mono    (26603): Probing 'SystemNative_OpenDir'. 03-18 15:02:42.122
>   D/Mono    (26603): Found as 'SystemNative_OpenDir'. 03-18 15:02:42.126
>   D/Mono    (26603): DllImport searching in: 'libmono-native.so'
>   ('./libmono-native.so'). 03-18 15:02:42.126 D/Mono    (26603):
>   Searching for 'SystemNative_ConvertErrorPalToPlatform'. 03-18
>   15:02:42.126 D/Mono    (26603): Probing
>   'SystemNative_ConvertErrorPalToPlatform'. 03-18 15:02:42.126 D/Mono
>   (26603): Found as 'SystemNative_ConvertErrorPalToPlatform'.

I suspect that it is connected to the way the directory and the files are handled on Android.

Question: How can I include the requirements from the first paragraph in a way that is compatible with the library being used under Windows and Xamarin.Froms/Android

Update 2020/03/27:
The reason has been that the content files didn't get copied to the Android project. This has been resolved by now. The new problem is, that even though the files are present in the build directory, the path "./Library" does not exist in the Android application. Since all this happens in the shared .NET library, I can't just put these files as Assets in the Android project and access them with the well-known mechanisms. How can I modify the shared library such that it can access its asset files?

Comment: According to your description, I am not sure if it is related to permission, for example WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions. More detailed info, please take a look:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=macos

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem persists unchanged.

Comment: I search some info according to your error message, and someone suggest you can uncheck "Use shared runtime" on Android options, you can try.

Comment: Doesn't work, either. In the meantime, It seems that it is related to files not getting copied into the APK even though they're in the binary directory of the application.

Comment: @H According to your update, do you want to get some file from shared library? If yes, please take a look this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51445888/read-file-in-shared-library-xamarin-c-sharp